# -split in PowerShell does not seem to work for me

Tags: powershell

I export a CSV file with SAM account name and MembersOf groups.
When I import that same CSV file and try to use the fields of group. I would to split them. When they are split I'm able to use them in `Add-ADPrincipalGroupMemberShip`.

```
elseif ($Answer -eq 'n') {
    Write-Warning "Verander de groepen in het CSV bestand: $ExCSV"
    Get-ADUser -Identity $ExSam -Properties sAMAccountName, MemberOf |
        Select-Object @{Name="User";expression={$ImSam}},
                      @{Name="Group";expression={$ImGroups}} |
        Export-Csv "$ExCSV" -Delimiter "," -Force -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
    [ValidateSet('OK')] $correct = Read-Host "Type 'OK' als je klaar bent"
    if ($correct = "OK") {
        $csv = Import-Csv "$ExCSV"        
        foreach ($user in $csv) {
            $csv2 = $csv.Group -replace ' ', ', '
        }

        Write-Output $csv2
        Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $ImSam -MemberOf "$csv2" 
        return
    }
}
```

The output I write is:

[image: csv2 output]

The error message I receive:

[image: error message]

My CSV:

[image]

Comment: Please always try to include as much information as possible _directly_ in the question, in _textual_ form. If you do need to use screen shots, embed them directly, don't link to them. The best approach to asking a question is to provide an [MCVE (Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Why are you writing your output to a CSV, then read the data back from that CSV? That usually just complicates matters. What is the value of `$ImGroups`? How do you populate that variable?

Comment: I'm trying to export AD groups from one member to another, I've got it working internally. However, if user A has 20 groups. but you want to import only 18 groups. You're able to remove 2 groups in the CSV before it will import the CSV

Comment: You could do the same with `$ImGroups` without the CSV detour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to transform a *string* that contains a list of names into an *array* of those names.

It is indeed the [`-split` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_split) that enables that, which allows sophisticated splitting of a string into an array of tokens using [regular expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions).

In the simplest case, if the string to split (`$csv.Group`, in  your case) is always in the form `'<name1>, <name2>[, ...]'`, use:

```
PS> 'test4, test5' -split ', '
test4
test5
```

To make this more robust to guard against leading and trailing whitespace and missing spaces after the comma:

```
PS> ' test4, test5,test6  ' -split ' +|,' -ne ''
test4
test5
test6
```

---

Specifically, you need an *array* of names rather than a string list, because `Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership`'s `-MemberOf` parameter expects an *array* of group identities (names).

Assuming that you've modified `$csv2` to contain an array, as described above, note that then you mustn't reference the variable enclosed in `"..."` (`"$csv2"`), as that would turn the value back into a (single) *string*.
Therefore, make the call as follows:

```
Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $ImSam -MemberOf $csv2 # !! No "..."
```